# How can I capture text from regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
Select * from users u 
WHERE 1=1
[IF(!"<<user_email>>".eqauls(""))
  AND u.user_email like '<<user_email>>'
]
[IF(!"<<user_name>>".eqauls(""))
  AND u.user_name 
   like '<<user_name>>'
]
```

in Above text. How can I capture start and end position between [IF(...] pattern?

I have tried this. But it is not working for me :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[IF\\(.*\\])",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Please define _"not working for me"_. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use non-greedy `.*?` instead of greedy `.*` quantifier, beside you don't need the start and the end parenthesis `(...)` :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[IF\\(.*?\\]", Pattern.DOTALL);
//-----------------------------------^^^
```

**Outputs**

```
[IF(!"<<user_email>>".eqauls(""))
  AND u.user_email like '<<user_email>>'
]
```

and

```
[IF(!"<<user_name>>".eqauls(""))
  AND u.user_name 
   like '<<user_name>>'
]
```